# Python Dates not working with MySQL Date coulmn

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-datetime

I am running a flask based web service and using python.

Configuration:
Python - 2.7.3 
MySQL - 5.5.31
Linux - 12.04.2

We have integrated to send a mail to a particular user only 2 times and we are storing the entry in a particular table.

CREATE TABLE `user_communication_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `mails_received` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '1',
  `current_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`current_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19592 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

We are using the above table to check how many user are getting how many mails. Each user can get a max of 2 mails for a day.

2 week back i encountered a issue that the 'mails_received' column is coming as 0. We are using SQL alchemy to do all stuff. I tried debugging a lot but everything seems to work fine. I tried in local seems to work fine. I thought it might be some issue so I restarted the issue.

**Catch:**
When I restarted the server everything seems to work fine on that day and I no longer got 0 in that column.

For tracking it I checked for 2 hours to be satisfied. I thought problem is resolved and went back to sleep. Again in morning i checked again it again went back to 0. I started worrying and again started debugging but thing seems to be on local. Again i restarted the server and again things started working fine. I don't why after restarting the server it works fine. In crontab I putted the job to restart the server.

We are using python `datetime` for this.

When we went to terminal on production and tried to run the same code without restarting the server it worked fine. I don't know what is the issue with web service.

Any help or insight can be helpful in debugging the issue.

Code:

```
def addRecord(user_id):
try:
    if recordExists(user_id):
        logging.info(" Entry for the user %s already exists. " % (user_id))
        return True
    # otherwise create an entry
    rowObj  = UserCommunicationSettingsDTO.empty()
    rowObj.user_id = user_id
    if BaseDAO.add(rowObj):
        logging.info("Entry %s successfully created" % (user_id))
        return True
    logging.error("Entry for the user %s could not be created. " % (user_id))
    return False

except Exception as error:
    logging.error("An entry into the table could not be made." + str(error))
    return False


def updateRecord(user_id, options):
try:
    # update record with current date
    if 'updated_date' not in options:
        options['updated_date'] = datetime.today().date()
    db_session = get_session()
    db_session. \
        query(UserCommunicationSettingsDTO). \
        filter(UserCommunicationSettingsDTO.user_id == user_id).update(options)
    db_session.commit()
    return True

except Exception as error:
    logging.error(" Error updating the values for user %s with error -- %s " % (user_id, str(error)))
    db_session.rollback()
    logging.error(" Rolling back ")
    return False


def recordExists(user_id):
try:
    db_session = get_session()
    record = db_session. \
        query(UserCommunicationSettingsDTO). \
        filter(UserCommunicationSettingsDTO.user_id == user_id).first()
    db_session.close()
    if record:
        logging.info("Record already exists for user %s" % (user_id))
        return record
    else:
        logging.info("Record doesn't exist for user %s" % (user_id))
        return None
except Exception as error:
    logging.error(" Error finding record for user %s . Error -- %s" % (user_id, str(error)))
    return None
```

Comment: How do you set the field?

Comment: @dim using .update({'coulmn_name' : value}) in sql alchemy

Comment: @dim its 1. When we add the first entry then it is set to 1. From there on its the incremental of the existing value.

Comment: But how is it set? You haven't given us much to go on. Can you share your code?

Comment: How do you call `updateRecord`? Where does `options` get set?

Comment: I call updateRecord method from the controller in another .py file. The options are like options = {'mails_received':1}. Like this it will get updated in the table using sql alchemy.

Comment: Since you check for the key before setting it, I would guess that `updated_date` can be set somewhere besides what you've shown. You need to find that and fix it. The code you've shown sets it to a `date`.